# SwiftUI issue with changing @Binding object in the second view

Tags: ios, swiftui

I want to change the object in the binding from the second screen but it's not working as i thought. I can change properties of the object but not the actual reference. If someone can explain why is that and what is the best way to achieve this ? From what i read @Binding doesn't work very well outside View. Also i included a workaround where i use second published property to update the ui but it's not a good solution in my opinion.. Am i doing something wrong or it's just how @Binding works ? (You can just copy and paste the code to see what i mean)

```
class TestModel {
   var text:String?
   
   init(text: String?) {
       self.text = text
   }
}

class FirstViewVM: ObservableObject {
   @Published var model:TestModel?
   @Published var showSecondView = false
}

struct FirstView: View {
   @StateObject var viewModel = FirstViewVM()
   
   var body: some View {
       VStack {
           Text(viewModel.model?.text ?? "n/a")
               .padding()
           Button("New model") {
               viewModel.model = TestModel(text: "New model from screen 1")
           }
           .padding()
           Button("Show screen 2") {
               viewModel.showSecondView = true
           }
           .padding()
       }
       .sheet(isPresented: $viewModel.showSecondView) {
           NavigationView {
               //First check the problem.. then use the workaround view to fix it....
               SecondView(viewModel: SecondViewVM(model: $viewModel.model))
//                SecondViewWorkaround(viewModel: SecondViewVMWorkaround(model: $viewModel.model))
           }
       }
   }
}


class SecondViewVM: ObservableObject {
   @Binding var model:TestModel?
   
   init(model: Binding<TestModel?>) {
       _model = model
   }
   
}

struct SecondView: View {
   @StateObject var viewModel:SecondViewVM
   
   var body: some View {
       VStack {
           Text(viewModel.model?.text ?? "n/a")
               .padding()
           Button("Edit model") {
               viewModel.objectWillChange.send()
               viewModel.model?.text = "Edited from screen 2"
           }
           .padding()
           //This will not update the UI
           Button("New model") {
               viewModel.objectWillChange.send()
               viewModel.model = TestModel(text: "New model from screen 2")
           }
           .padding()
       }
   }
}


//Workaround....First check the views above..
class SecondViewVMWorkaround: ObservableObject {
   @Binding var model:TestModel? {
       didSet{
           modelUsedForUI = model //Passing the changes to the other model that is used for ui
       }
   }
   @Published var modelUsedForUI:TestModel? //Added another published var that will update the ui
   
   init(model: Binding<TestModel?>) {
       _model = model
       modelUsedForUI = model.wrappedValue
   }
   
   
}

struct SecondViewWorkaround: View {
   @StateObject var viewModel:SecondViewVMWorkaround
   
   var body: some View {
       VStack {
           Text(viewModel.modelUsedForUI?.text ?? "n/a")
               .padding()
           Button("Edit model") {
               viewModel.objectWillChange.send()
               viewModel.model?.text = "Edited from screen 2"
           }
           .padding()
           Button("New model") {
               viewModel.objectWillChange.send()
               viewModel.model = TestModel(text: "New model from screen 2")
           }
           .padding()
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: binding is a way to add property value to your view which is defined elsewhere  please read this explains it https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/what-is-the-binding-property-wrapper

Answer (score 0):

I think there is some over-complication in your code when you created a second view model to pass to the second view, and tried to link two view models instead of linking the views. `@Binding` is a wrapper to use in a `View` when passing `@State` variables. You are instead using it between two view models, I don't think it can work as you intend.

I suggest a different approach:

1. Use only one view model that integrates all functionalities you need.
2. Create an `@ObservedObject` in your second view.
3. Pass the view model from your first to your second view.

The example below works, you want to try it:

**1. Only one view model**

```
class TestModel {
   var text:String?
   
   init(text: String?) {
       self.text = text
   }
}

class FirstViewVM: ObservableObject {
   @Published var model:TestModel?
   @Published var showSecondView = false
    
    // Merge here the functionalities of your second view model, or
    // just create an instance, like:
    // @Published var secondVM = SecondViewModel()
}
```

**2. and 3. Pass the same view model from the first to the second view**

```
struct FirstView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel = FirstViewVM()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(viewModel.model?.text ?? "n/a")
                .padding()
            Button("New model") {
                viewModel.model = TestModel(text: "New model from screen 1")
            }
            .padding()
            Button("Show screen 2") {
                viewModel.showSecondView = true
            }
            .padding()
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $viewModel.showSecondView) {
            NavigationView {
                
                // Just pass the same model from one view to another
                SecondView(viewModel: viewModel)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct SecondView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: FirstViewVM      // Read your model here
   
   var body: some View {
       VStack {
           Text(viewModel.model?.text ?? "n/a")
               .padding()
           Button("Edit model") {
               viewModel.objectWillChange.send()
               viewModel.model?.text = "Edited from screen 2"
           }
           .padding()
           
           // Now it updates
           Button("New model") {
               viewModel.objectWillChange.send()
               viewModel.model = TestModel(text: "New model from screen 2")
           }
           .padding()
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you're doing something wrong. With Swift and SwiftUI we use the advantages of value types that fix the consistency problems you are facing. So your model should be a struct, e.g.

```
struct TestModel {
   var text: String
   
   init(text: String) {
       self.text = text
   }
}
```

Then an object is used manage the life-cycle and side-effect of the model structs, e.g.

```
class Model: ObservableObject {
   @Published var testModel: TestModel?

   // funcs to load and save etc.
    func newTestModel(text: String) {
         testModel = TestModel(text: text)
    }
}
```

Also in SwiftUI we don't design our Views based on screens, we break them up depending on the data they need. So they should be something like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var model = Model()
    @State var showSecondView = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if let testModel = model.testModel {
                ContentView2(testModel: testModel)
            }
            Button("New model") {
                model.newTestModel(text: "from screen 1")
            }
            .padding()
            Button("Show screen 2") {
                showSecondView = true
            }
            .padding()
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $showSecondView) {
            NavigationView {
                
                // Just pass the same model from one view to another
                SecondView(model: model)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView2: View {
    let testModel: TextModel

    var body: some View {
        Text(testModel.text ?? "n/a")
        .padding()
    }
}

struct SecondView: View {
    @ObservableObject var model: Model
   
   var body: some View {
       VStack {
           if let testModel = model.testModel {
               Button("Edit model") {
                   testModel.text = "Edited from screen 2"
               }
               .padding()
           }
               // Now it updates
           Button("New model") {
               model.newTestModel(text: "New model from screen 2")
           }
           .padding()
       }
   }
}
```

Note: when we want to present data on a sheet we use [`sheet(item:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/sheet(item:ondismiss:content:)) rather than the boolean version.

Comment: I agree that the model should be struct. But other than that i want to have viewmodel for every screen. It holds the business logic, different services and will be different for every screen (Yes you can have composition of views and viewmodel for every subview but i am just simplifying the example). We can can pass around the same viewmodel but this doesn't seem like a good solution to me. I thought that with binding i can pass only the specific data that i need from the first viewmodel to the second and it's working unless i change the reference.. leading to ui not refreshing itself.

Comment: You can pass a binding to edit the struct however if you want to call methods in the model you need a reference to it aswell. Usually we use the environment for the model object so it is available everywhere without passing it. We don't use view model objects in swiftui but we do use @State with a custom struct containing logic, that's what sheet(item:) is designed to work with (there is a code sample in the docs). Then you would take the data from that struct and use it to edit the model, you wouldn't edit the model data directly, otherwise it wouldn't be cancellable.